# "Circular reference caused by ..." error in Access SQL (but not in T-SQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have the following SQL statement which returns the desired result in SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT
    S.ONOMA
    , S.DIEY
    , S.POLH
    , S.TK
    , S.IDIOT
    , S.KODIKOS
    , S.AFM
FROM 
    SYNERG AS S
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT
         G.AFM, MIN(KODIKOS) AS KODIKOS
     FROM SYNERG AS G
     WHERE LEN(ISNULL(AFM, '')) != 0
     GROUP BY AFM) AS I ON S.KODIKOS = I.KODIKOS
ORDER BY
    S.AFM
```

but when I run the same SQL statement in MS Access 2007 I get an error:

> Circular reference caused by 'KODIKOS' in query definition's SELECT list.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See [ACC: "Circular Reference Caused by Alias" Error Message](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/97526)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/97526) by HansUp:

> The alias of a calculated field cannot be identical to any of the field names used to calculate the field.

This can be rather annoying (esp. if it is a field that is returned by the query), but there is no way around it.

So you need to change the alias, e.g.:

```
SELECT
    S.ONOMA
    , S.DIEY
    , S.POLH
    , S.TK
    , S.IDIOT
    , S.KODIKOS
    , S.AFM
FROM 
    SYNERG AS S
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT
         G.AFM, MIN(KODIKOS) AS MinKODIKOS
     FROM SYNERG AS G
     WHERE LEN(Nz(AFM, '')) <> 0
     GROUP BY AFM) AS I ON S.KODIKOS = I.MinKODIKOS
ORDER BY
    S.AFM
```

Note also that an `IsNull()` function exists in Access, but has a different meaning (it takes one argument and returns a Boolean). The corresponding function is `Nz()`

And (thanks @HansUp), the unequal operator is `<>`, not `!=`. I always use `<>` in SQL Server too, no need to make things more complicated than necessary. :)

Comment: I think Access will complain: *Invalid use of '.', '!', or '()'. in query expression '!=0'.*  If so, use `<>` instead of `!=`, or check whether the length is greater than zero: `LEN(Nz(AFM, '')) > 0`

Comment: Thanks, missed that one. @HansUp